# Roll two dice, you can stop whenever, but if you roll the same face twice in a row you lose everything

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

> Suppose we play a game with a die where we roll and sum our rolls. We can stop any time and take
> the sum as our score, but if we roll the same face twice in a row we lose everything. What strategy
> will maximize our expected score?

If the last face rolled is r and our current sum is S, then the expected value of our score if we roll again is

$$\frac{1}{6}0 + \frac{5}{6}S+ \frac{1}{6}(\sum_{i=1, i \neq r}^{6}i)$$

Surely if you are conditioning on the next throw it should have been

$$\frac{1}{6}0 + \frac{5}{6}(S+ \frac{1}{6}(\sum_{i=1, i \neq r}^{6}i))$$

Where is the error in my logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we condition on not throwing $r$, then there are only $5$ remaining possible results on the die. So it should be
$$
\frac160+\frac56\left(S+\frac15\sum_{i=1,i\neq r}^6i\right)
$$
Expand the bracket, and you get the first result.

Alternatively, consider the expected score after throwing the die, but without the rule that a throw of $r$ kills your score. It would be
$$
\frac16\sum_{i=1}^6\left(S+i\right)
$$
Now, if we reinstate the rule, one of these terms becomes $0$ and the other five remain untouched.